# Identify the postgres extension version shows different versions

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

Have a postgres database with extensions

If I do psql>\dx it shows

```
oracle_fdw, 1.1, foreign data wrapper for Oracle access
```

But if I do psql>SELECT oracle_diag('oraclegwserver'); it says

```
oracle_fdw 2.0.0, PostgreSQL 10.0, Oracle client 11.2.0.3.0, Oracle server 11.2.0.2.0
```

Which version is correct or used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is the extension version, which changes only if the extension's objects change. The second is the version of oracle_fdw.

See [the documentation](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw):

> Note that the extension version as shown by the psql command `\x` or the system catalog `pg_available_extensions` is not the installed version of oracle_fdw. To get the oracle_fdw version, use the function `oracle_diag`.